# Class is added for A element, but not showing up?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a search box that suggests different names depending on what you type in the box. When you use arrow keys (up or down) it adds class to each corresponding name. I can see in the console.log that the style is added, but the color is not changing. I don't understand what is going on.

**Here is my HTML:**

```html
<div class="container">
  <h4>AJAX - Search Form</h4>
  <br>

  <form autocomplete="off">
    <div style="width:300px;">
      <input type="text" onkeyup='ajaxSearch(this,event)' id="searchbox" name="searchbox" placeholder="Search for a name...">
      <input type="submit" name="q" id="send" placeholder="Etsi">
    </div>
  </form>
  
  <div id="resultsDiv"></div>
</div>
```

**And here is my JS:**

```js
var index = -1;
var resultUrl = "";
var searchURLResults;
var resultsDiv = document.getElementById('resultsDiv');
var input = document.getElementById('searchbox');

function ajaxSearch(field, event) {
  /*************** ONKEYUP ************/
  var keyCode = event.keyCode;
  if (keyCode == 40) {
    index++;
    if (index >= resultsDiv.childElementCount) {
      index = resultsDiv.childElementCount - 1;
    }
    highlight();
  } else if (keyCode == 38) {
    index--;
    if (index >= resultsDiv.childElementCount) {
      index = resultsDiv.childElementCount + 1;
    }
    highlight();
  } else if (keyCode == 27) {
    field.value = "";
    closeAllLists(resultsDiv);
  }

  /*************** AJAX ************/
  try {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
  if (input.value !== "") {
    resultsDiv.innerHTML = "";
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var persons = xhr.responseText.split('\t');
        personsToDiv(persons);
      }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'ajax-suggest.php?q=' + input.value, true);
    xhr.send();
  }
}

function personsToDiv(persons) {
  if (persons.length !== 0 && resultsDiv.children.length == 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
      var a = document.createElement('A');
      a.setAttribute("class", "search-item");
      a.href = "#";
      var name = document.createTextNode(persons[i]);
      a.appendChild(name);
      resultsDiv.appendChild(a);
      a.setAttribute("href", "ajax-suggest.php?q=" + persons[i]);

    }
  }
}

/*************** HIGHLIGHTER ************/
function highlight() {
  for (var i = 0; i < resultsDiv.childElementCount; i++) {
    var suggestion = resultsDiv.childNodes[i];
    console.log(suggestion);
    if (i === index) {
      suggestion.style = "background-color:violet";
    }
  }
}

function closeAllLists(resultsDiv) {
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName('search-item');
  while (resultsDiv.firstChild) {
    resultsDiv.removeChild(resultsDiv.lastChild);
  }
}
```

Comment: have you check if it not got overide. try adding !important

Comment: I tried adding !important, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: When I `console.log(resultsDiv)` inside the `personsToDiv(persons)` it outputs the resultsDiv twice when I enter one letter in the search box. Can this be the solution to my problem? Why is it console.logging it twice?